# Insert figure as an equation: how do you move the numbering so that it is at the middle right of the figure?

Tags: floats, equations, positioning

[image]

I have inserted a figure within an equation and as you can see the (1) is at the bottom right, I would like the equation label (1) to be middle right of the figure. Has anyone any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX  SX! It would be much simpler to type the equation from within LaTeX! What is your exact code?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. If the equation number is placed below rather than to the side of the math material, it's almost invariably because the math material -- in your case, a 20 x 20 matrix encased by parentheses -- is simply too wide. Since you haven't provided *any information* about how the equation was created or about the document class, the font size, the fonts, etc. it's not possible to provide a more elaborate diagnosis of what's going on, let alone offer a cure.

Comment: it isn't clear why you are including this as an image, but if you do, just include it at a slightly smaller size, the (1) isn't moved because it is an image, it is moved because there is no room.

Answer (score 7):

You can insert the matrix as an image by something like

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{image-file}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
```

On the other hand, it took just a few minutes to implement the explicit matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\zeros}{m}
 {
  0 \prg_replicate:nn { #1 - 1 } { & 0 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2pt}
\mathcal{H}_{20}=
\begin{pmatrix}
v_a & t_1 & \zeros{17} & t_1 \\
t_1 & v_b & t_2 & \zeros{17} \\
\zeros{1}  & t_2 & v_a & t_1 & \zeros{16} \\
\zeros{2}  & t_1 & v_b & t_2 & \zeros{15} \\
\zeros{3}  & t_2 & v_a & t_1 & \zeros{14} \\
\zeros{4}  & t_1 & v_b & t_2 & \zeros{13} \\
\zeros{5}  & t_2 & v_a & t_2 & \zeros{12} \\
\zeros{6}  & t_1 & v_b & t_2 & \zeros{11} \\
\zeros{7}  & t_2 & v_a & t_1 & \zeros{10} \\
\zeros{8}  & t_1 & v_b & t_2 & \zeros{9} \\
\zeros{9}  & t_2 & v_a & t_2 & \zeros{8} \\
\zeros{10} & t_2 & v_b & t_1 & \zeros{7} \\
\zeros{11} & t_1 & v_a & t_2 & \zeros{6} \\
\zeros{12} & t_2 & v_b & t_1 & \zeros{5} \\
\zeros{13} & t_1 & v_a & t_2 & \zeros{4} \\
\zeros{14} & t_2 & v_b & t_1 & \zeros{3} \\
\zeros{15} & t_1 & v_a & t_2 & \zeros{2} \\
\zeros{16} & t_2 & v_b & t_1 & \zeros{1} \\
\zeros{17} & t_1 & v_a & t_2 \\
t_1 & \zeros{17} & t_2 & v_b \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]